# как поместить кнопку между 2-мя секциями

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите пожалуйста как поместить кнопку между 2-мя секциями (как показано на картинке), пробую абсолютом, но при адаптивности она плывет.

```
<section class="five-reasons">
<div class="container">
...
<div>
</section>
<section class="six-results">
<button class="btn btn-default">регистрация</button>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="info-six-results col-md-12 text-center">
<h1>6 результатов, которые вы получите:</h1>
</div>
...
</div>
<div>
</section>

.six-results button{
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px;
    top: -30px;
}

.six-results button.btn-default{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #473D97;
    color: #FFE06F;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    left: 500px;
    top: -30px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" style="background:black">
 <br /> <br /> <br />
  секция 1
  <br /> <br /> <br />
</div>
<div class="container text-center">
    <p  style=" margin: 0">
      <button  style="position:absolute; margin-top: -15px" >кнопка</button>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="container"  style="background: blue">
  <br /> <br /> <br />
секция 2 
  <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
</div>
```

Comment: я в css наверно не правильно прописываю, потому что я указываю кнопке абсолютное позиционирование, но она никак не хочет по центра становится, уходить немного в право, а если начинаю ей давать left или right, то она вообще в конце уплывает